# Find the stationary points of: $V=(2/r^3)-(3/r^2)$

Tags: stationary-point

I've applied the exponent rules and differentiated to get to the point where i have

$$dr/dv=-6r^{-4}+6r^{-3}$$

I'm starting to get very confused with the math when i set the LHS = 0 in order to find the value of stationary points.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Comment: Hi, welcome to math.SE! Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Answer (score 1):

So we have $$-6r^{-4}+6r^{-3}=0\implies 6r^{-4}=6r^{-3}\implies {6\over r^4}={6\over r^3}\;\;/\cdot r^4$$

$$\implies 6=6r\implies r=1$$